# mysql trigger on update to populate another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to this TRIGGER thing and it is beating me up pretty good.

The intention is to populate a price history table every time a price change occurs on table prices.

So far my attempts are taking all prices changes each time one price is updated, or not working at all.

I basically did not get this logic, so that I can limit it to the one price being updated, not all of the updates.

This below is a bit of a pseudo-code.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER price_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON prices FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

 INSERT INTO prices_history (version_id,price,data_change)
 SELECT version_id, price, time_update FROM prices WHERE????? ;
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

table prices (summarized)

```
version_id smallint(4) primary
price decimal (10,0)
time_update timestamp
```

table prices_history

```
price_id int(5) primary
version_id smallint(4)
price decimal (10,0)
data_change datetime
```

Comment: Can you share the table layout of prices_history and prices?

Comment: If `OLD.price <> NEW.price` then insert history record?

Comment: not really. version_id is the unique identifier and is connected to another table ( versions ). So that should be fine

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks, It might be so. Can you elaborate a complete answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `SELECT` inside the trigger, as that will use all the rows from table. You have available the columns from the changed row directly. Also you can use `OLD.` and `NEW.` for distinguishing between the values before and after UPDATE.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER price_update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON prices
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO prices_history SET
    price = NEW.price,
    version_id = NEW.version_id, // or OLD.version_id
    data_change = NEW.time_update; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Interesting. But there should be no price_old and price_new going into prices_history, but rather EVERY price change with its date/time coming from table prices, as well as the version_id

Comment: No problem, then just use `price=OLD.price, version_id=version_id, data_change=time_update`. You can use any column from the `prices` table after the `=` sign.

Comment: yes, I was in the process of doing that and it seems to work. Just give me a second to confirm.

Comment: well, does not work. if I make it as you mentioned on your last comment it will not accept the change on table prices giving error 'field time_update does not exist', which is very strange as it does exist

Comment: continuing... if I leave 'data_change = NOW(); ', it will work, but the field version_id on prices_history will not populate.

Comment: apparently it will not work if I do not use NEW() for version_id and time_update. Actually for version_id I can use either NEW() or OLD(). I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

prices table should have price_id - not version_id

Then

```
select @max_version = max(version_no)+1 from price_history where price_id = @changed_price_id
INSERT INTO prices_history (price_id, version_id,price,data_change)
 SELECT price_id_id, @max_version, price, time_update FROM prices WHERE price_id = @changed_price_id
```

;

Comment: I reiterate my comment concerning version_id. Not planning the change my whole database structure to accommodate this trigger